# NameError in Django

Tags: python-2.7, django-views

I am working with Django/python and ran into a few errors I can't seem to find relevant answers for online.

I was testing the following from views.py:

```
def teamRoster(request, pk): #shows list of players

    tempteams = Teams.objects.get(id=pk)
    tempteams = tempteams.players.all()
    team = get_object_or_404(Teams, id=pk)

    context = {
        'teamList': tempteams,
        'team': team,
    }

return render(request, "roster/teamRoster.html", context)
```

What I get in the shell:

```
from roster.models import Teams, Player
tempteams=Teams.objects.get(id=pk)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'pk' is not defined
```

If I try the next line:

```
tempteams = tempteams.players.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module> 

NameError: name 'tempteams' is not defined
```

My data does have a pk attribute that I put in when making my json file instead of having one automatically assigned. I'm not sure where I need to be defining pk. I'm fairly new with django/python but I did do something similar with another definition (same project) and it works fine. Any guidance would be much appreciated. And if it helps, my models and other parts of the code are at https://github.com/historymaiden/Athletic-Team-App - the app is called roster.

Answer (score 0):

You have not yet defined pk in the shell which is why you are getting the error there

```
from roster.models import Teams, Player
tempteams=Teams.objects.get(id=pk)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'pk' is not defined
```

Because the last code block failed then tempteams is not defined either

```
tempteams = tempteams.players.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module> 

NameError: name 'tempteams' is not defined
```